# How to tilt the edges to a particular angle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves, transforms

[image]

Hi, can anybody help me to fulfill my requirement.
I want to move the arms a bit down if you see the man sculpture then it seems that angle of arms with body's side portion is somewhat 90deg but I want to the arms a bit down so that they make angle around 60deg. I tried the Rotation but it is rotating the complete arms.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by using rotation so I rotated the arms along Y-axis then it looked weird as the arms were rotated as so far from the body, then I used the provided axes to set the position of arms back to the position relative to body. 
Now it looks correct as I wanted:

[image]